# How to control the brightness of this 7 segment LED display?

Tags: 7segmentdisplay

This is how I tried to connect a BT-M512RD-DR1 LED panel, but it doesn't really work. This is the [datasheet](http://megachip.ru/pdf/BRI/BT-M512RD-DR1.pdf). Basically I have just used 2 wires of the 10 k\$\Omega\$ potentiometer. There is no change in brightness.

[image]

So again, the question is - what is the proper way to connect the brightness control pot to the LED display?

Comment: Datasheet gives you an application circuit on how to connect the brightness pot. Look at page3 block diagram. Also look at page 4 where they describe how to control the brightness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the datasheet more carefully.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Same here - I'm too slow on the draw.

Comment: Is that a capacitor connected between ground and brt control pin? If yes, what should be the value?

Comment: @Pablo looks like it. I suspect it's to eliminate any noise on the brightness. I'd use whatever value of decoupling capacitor you have handy by the bucketful, like 100nF.

Answer (score 1):

The datasheet describes the function of brightness control as such.

[image]

It specifies a maximum current of 550uA into this pin.

The datasheet describes an 18-pin device; you show an 8 pin device.  In the datasheet, the brightness control pin is pin 18, while you're using pin 3.

Comment: It's actually socket, to which LED display is connected.

Comment: Okay, then you're using an 8-pin socket with an 18-pin device.

Answer (score 0):

From your schematic it is a bit hard to tell what is what. But just to double check, you have the display connected like this, correct?

[image: 7 seg display connection]

So it looks like the pin 18 of the display need to be connected between the variable resistor and ground.